# How to display the next three images click on load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a load more button to display the image. On page load, I am displaying 3 images and after click on load more button, then next 3 images will display on the screen.

I tried below code but it's not working. would you help me out in this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item").slice(0, 2).show(); // select the first ten
  $("#load").click(function(e) { // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".item:hidden").slice(0, 2).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
    if ($(".item:hidden").length == 0) { // check if any hidden divs still exist
      alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lightgallery1 a {
  width: 30.33%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0;
}

.lightgallery1 a img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightgallery1">
  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

</div>

<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css was wrong. Use:

```
.lightgallery1 a {
  display: none;
}
```

Your code shows 2 images. If you want to show 3 change `.slice(0, 2)` to `.slice(0, 3)`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item").slice(0, 2).show(); // select the first ten
  $("#load").click(function(e) { // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".item:hidden").slice(0, 2).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
    if ($(".item:hidden").length == 0) { // check if any hidden divs still exist
      alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lightgallery1 a {
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0;
  display: none;
}

.lightgallery1 a img {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightgallery1">
  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

  <a href="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg" class="item"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg"></a>

</div>
<div>
<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the class="item" for first two anchor tag.

Comment: @user9437856 As a side note. Your images are always on your site (not visible but they are there) because they are in the html. That causes all images to be loaded from the source consuming some bandwidth. A better approach is to load the images dynamically  and append the html in your gallery when people press load more. The answer of wscourge is one example of how to do it. Another way could be to use ajax to load it from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```js
var links = [
    "https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg",
  "https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg",
  "https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg",
  "https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg",
  "https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg",
  "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg",
];

var $gallery  = $(".lightgallery1").first();
var $loadMore = $("#load");

function loadMore(e) {
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     
    if(links.length) {

      var src   = links.pop();
      var $link = $("<a>");
      var $img  = $("<img>");

      $img.attr("src", src);
      $link.attr("href", src).addClass("item");
      
      $link.append($img);
      $gallery.append($link);

    } else {
      $loadMore.hide();
    }
    
  }
  
}

$loadMore.on("click", loadMore);
loadMore();
```

```css
.lightgallery1 a {
  width: 30.33%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 0;
}

.lightgallery1 a img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
 /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightgallery1"></div>

<button id="load">Load More</button>
```