# Show More and Show Less button in a HTML file

Tags: html, button

I have a html file where I put six images positioned in the following form: three images (side by side) and under them another three images side by side. I want to put a Show More button after the first three images and a Show Less button after all six images are displayed. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is awfully similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538010/how-to-display-the-next-three-images-click-on-load-more-button)

Don't ask a question before looking for others similar to it.